# Reduce html file loading time in phonegap application ios?

Tags: html, ios, cordova, splash-screen

iam working on a simple phonegap application in that it takes around 3 minute to load the file(for showing home page )  till that time it showing the splash image(launch screen) is there any way to make it fast???

Total "WWW" folder file size is 5.3MB
**my app delegate application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() show below**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];


#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
#endif
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
#else
        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif
    self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;

    // Set your app's start page by setting the <content src='foo.html' /> tag in config.xml.
    // If necessary, uncomment the line below to override it.
    // self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";

    // NOTE: To customize the view's frame size (which defaults to full screen), override
    // [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've known other people with similar issues (but not 3 minute delays!), I'm not sure there is much you can do, I think we need to wait for the PhoneGap people to develop a system that makes it more efficient in loading.